# Concat Minified files & skip Minification using Grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bundling-and-minification, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-concat

Currently I writing a Grunt Build file ; which uses "usemin" I have created 3 Blocks in HTML which would create 3 files assets.min.js , lib.min.js etc..

```
<!-- build:js js/assets.min.js --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-cache.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-animate.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-touch.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-cookies.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script> 
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This works fine. But There are 2 major problems I am facing with it...

1. Angular shows error "Uncaught error [$injector:modulerr]..
2. It seems Usemin is also miniifying the files again.

I also tried 2nd option, by just concatinating these files i.e bypassing minification step avoiding Usemin.. still the *same error*

Please guide

Comment: please have a look at https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin it does the angular minification preparation for youe.

Comment: I am using "ng-min" already. But not sure whats the problem.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am also already using ng-min and get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses something called dependency injection to resolve your arguments. Angular knows what each object is by its name.

"$scope" will be initialised as a scope object because it is named "$scope". After usemin, this variable will be called something else, like "a", to save bytes. Angular doesn't know what "a" is and throws an error.

You can solve this like so:

1. Read here about the minification of angular apps 
   http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05
2. Either follow the guide manually or use **ngmin** process BEFORE you run uglify.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by 2 ways.

1. use unminified files in usemin block

```
<!-- build:js js/assets.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-cache.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-route.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-animate.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-touch.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/angular-cookies.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/assets/js/lib/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

2. Copy scripts using grunt task

```
copy:{
  scripts:{
    files:[{
      expand: true, 
      cwd:'<%= config.app %>',
      dest: '<%= config.tmp %>', src: ['app/assets/js/lib/**/*.min.js']
    }]
  },
}
```